# Orientation of image using EXIF or Cursor always 0

Tags: android-camera, android-orientation, android-cursor

I am taking pictures from my portrait camera app and send to the server.Before sending i need to rotate image if necessary.So i'm saving the image in the sdcard and tried to get the Exif or Cursor.I went through most of the post related to this.But nothing works for me.Here is the code..

1. **ExifInterface**

   ```
    File imageFile = new File(uri.toString());
   ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
   int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,   ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
   ```

   Here the orientation is always 0 for any image
2. **Cusor**

   ```
   int orientation = 0;
   final String[] projection = new String[] { MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION };
   final Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext()
                   .getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null,
                           null, null); 
   if (cursor != null) {
   final int orientationColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION);
   if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      orientation = cursor.isNull(orientationColumnIndex) ? 0 : cursor.getInt(orientationColumnIndex);
    }
   ```

   here also the image rotation is zero.How can i find the exact rotation of the image ? Any help will be greatly appreciated..

Comment: Any luck on this? Having similar problems?

Comment: Hi! I m having exactly the same issue. Exif always returning 0 and the cursor is always null...did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Please start to use ExifInterface from support libraries. It offers a constructor which support InputStream. Getting path from Uri is buggy.
You need this library:compile 'com.android.support:exifinterface:25.3.1' in your build.gradle.
code

```
private float getOrientation (InputStream image, Uri photoURI) {
    //ExifInterface myExif = new ExifInterface(photoURI.getPath());

    float photoRotation = 0;
    boolean hasRotation = true;

    try {
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(image);
        int exifRotation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

        switch (exifRotation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED: {
                hasRotation = false;
            }
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90: {
                photoRotation = 90.0f;
                break;
            }
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180: {
                photoRotation = 180.0f;
                break;
            }
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270: {
                photoRotation = 270.0f;
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("ODDREAMS", e.getMessage());
    }

    if (!hasRotation) {
        try {
                String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION};
                Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(photoURI, columns, null, null, null);

                if (cursor == null) return 0;

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    int orientationColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(columns[1]);
                    photoRotation = cursor.getInt(orientationColumnIndex);
                    Log.d("ODDREAMS", "CURSOR " + photoRotation);
                }
                cursor.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}

    }

    return photoRotation;
}
```